# PHP sending emails to but not text

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am trying to send emails to phones that have Verizon numbers. Here is my code right now

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');
function Send( $ToEmail, $MessageHTML, $MessageTEXT) {
  require_once ( 'classes/phpmailer/phpmailer.php' ); // Add the path as appropriate
  $Mail = new PHPMailer();
  $Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
  $Mail->Host        = "box405.bluehost.com"; // Sets SMTP server
  $Mail->SMTPDebug   = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
  $Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
  $Mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; //Secure conection
  $Mail->Port        = 465; // set the SMTP port
  $Mail->Username    = 'techsupport@test.com'; // SMTP fake account username
  $Mail->Password    = 'password1'; // SMTP fake account password
  $Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
  $Mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
  $Mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
  $Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
  $Mail->FromName    = 'Tech support';
  $Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line

  $Mail->AddAddress( $ToEmail ); // To:
  $Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
  $Mail->Body    = $MessageHTML;
  $Mail->AltBody = $MessageTEXT;
  $Mail->Send();
  $Mail->SmtpClose();

  if ( $Mail->IsError() ) { // ADDED - This error checking was missing
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
    return TRUE;
  } 
}
$stmt = $db->prepare("select phone From members where phone not like 'no';");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$ToEmail = $result[0][0];
$ToName  = 'techsupport';
$MessageHTML = "test";
$MessageTEXT = 'test';
$Send = Send( $ToEmail, $MessageHTML, $MessageTEXT);
if ( $Send ) {
  echo "<h2> Sent OK</h2>";
}
else {
  echo "<h2> ERROR</h2>";
}
die;
?>
```

this works when I try to send emails but when I use it to send texts it says sent but I do not receive anything. I know this is not because of the address because I use the same address when I text myself from gmail and it is not the sql query because I have tested it . I Think the problem is in the smtp or phpmailer for I have not used either of those a lot. Also the code runs though and prints out the SENT OK echo but nothing goes through and no errors.

[EDIT] To answer ironcito's question I am sending the email to

```
phonenumber@vtext.com
```

I know this works because I have used the same address through gmail.

Comment: If I were Verizon, and you were trying to send texts to my customers that said they were from "tech support", I would block your IP immediately. You may want to make that less generic.

Comment: I don't know what's stored in the database, but it seems like you're trying to send an email to a bare phone number. Shouldn't you add a domain or something?

Comment: Are you able to check if the text-only email reaches the receiving server? Can it be the case that it is regarded as spam and therefore note delivered? Try sending the email with content type text/plain and normal priority to see if it works better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because you push the content to the mail (body) before you set the content (messagehtml/messagetext), which creates an empty email. Try changing these around, that might be the solution.

Comment: Could you please post an example of what you mean?